# How to disable particular route when other one is active in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have two components sports and entertainment. I want that when my sports route is active then user should not have its access to entertainment route. How can i do this??

routing code from my  App.js file

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/home" component={Main} />
    <Route path="/sports" component={Sports} />
    <Route path="/entertainment" component={Entertainment} />
   
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: mybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321601/easier-way-to-to-disable-link-in-react

Answer (score 1):

You could split into two sections.

Just for example:

```
const Routers = () => {
  const toggleRoutesPermission = true // should get the permission value from somewhere

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/home" component={Main} />
        {
          toggleRoutesPermission
            ? <Route path="/sports" component={Sports} />
            : <Route path="/entertainment" component={Entertainment} />
        }
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```