# How to disable the Material UI Link API component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I was previously using Material UI's Button component, which has the disable property. Basically that prop allows the button to be disabled based on a boolean. So if true, then it is disabled. However, now I want to switch to the Material UI Link component which is also a button, but it looks like a text. It does the same thing a button does, but looks like a link. However, it does not have the disable property or it seems because I dont see it as a possible property in the Material UI docs. Is there any work around for this?

*Note - This is not from the React Router Dom library. I am using the Link from Material UI Library for React. Just so there is no confusion.

```
<Link
  hover
  underline="hover"
  variant="body2"
  onClick={
    this.buyAll
  }>
Buy All Products
</Link>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easier way to to disable link in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321601/easier-way-to-to-disable-link-in-react)

Comment: @beskgar thanks for your effort, but it does not answer my question. The link that they are referring to in that post is from React Router Dom library. The link I am referring to is from the Material UI Library

Comment: @kenny229 It doesn't matter that it's a different `Link` component in this here, it still works. Try the idea in the linked post out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Material-UI's `Link` renders as an [`<a>` element by default](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui/src/Link/Link.js#L62). If you want it to render as a `<button>` (which would be appropriate when you are specifying `onClick` and not specifying `href`), then you need to specify `component="button"`. Once you have done that, the `disabled` prop will work as expected with the caveat that Material-UI's `Link` doesn't have any styling for a "disabled" look; so if you want the link to look different when it is disabled, you will need to customize the styles for that state.

Below is a working example including some sample disabled styling:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiLink from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > * + *": {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  }
}));

const Link = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&[disabled]": {
      color: "grey",
      cursor: "default",
      "&:hover": {
        textDecoration: "none"
      }
    }
  }
})(MuiLink);

export default function Links() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Typography className={classes.root}>
      <Link component="button" onClick={() => console.log("hello")}>
        Link
      </Link>
      <Link
        component="button"
        disabled
        onClick={() =>
          console.log(
            "I'm disabled so this doesn't appear in the console when this is clicked."
          )
        }
      >
        Disabled Link
      </Link>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Disabled Link/button]

Answer (score 4):

Thank [@RyanCogswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell). I tried to improve [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421327/how-to-disable-the-material-ui-link-api-component#answer-67425607) by defining a custom theme, based on MUI's default theme and using `pointer-events: none`:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

const { palette } = createTheme() // MUI's default theme

const theme = createTheme({ // Our app's custom theme
  MuiLink: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '&[disabled]': {
          color: palette.action.disabled,
          pointerEvents: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```js
import { Link } from '@mui/material'

//...

<Link
  disabled
  aria-disabled
  tabIndex={-1}
  to='https://stackoverflow.com/a/72479343/5318303'
>
  Disabled link
</Link>
```

(You need to add `aria-disabled: true` for accessibility reasons, and `tabIndex: -1` so the link is not selectable via keyboard).