# Can I disable an anchor tag with respect to an if condition which return a string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have made an anchor tag (not a button) text to redirect me to another page

```
<StyledTableCell align="center">
   <Link href={`/races/results/${race.id}`}>{race.race_name}</Link>
</StyledTableCell>
```

And I do have a status column that indicates the race status.

```
<StyledTableCell align="center">                                        
   {getRaceStatus(race.start_date_time, race.end_date_time)}
</StyledTableCell>
```

My getRaceStatus is,

```
export const getRaceStatus = (start_date, end_date) => {
const now = new Date();
const startX = new Date(start_date);
const endX = new Date(end_date);
if (startX.getTime() > now.getTime()) {
    return 'Coming Soon';
}
if (startX.getTime() <= now.getTime() && now.getTime() < endX.getTime()) {
    return 'Open';
} else {
    return 'Finished';
}
```

};

So, I wanted to disable my link when the status is not equal to 'open'

Can someone please help me out with this? I have tried to get it done but I wanted something short and easy way to get the requirement done.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would only placing a `<Link>` when the status is `Open`, otherwise just a `span` be ok to implement?

```
<StyledTableCell align="center">
   {getRaceStatus === 'Open' ? 
        <Link href={`/races/results/${race.id}`}>{race.race_name}</Link> :
        <span>{race.race_name}</span>
   }
</StyledTableCell>
```

If not, you could [follow this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321601/easier-way-to-to-disable-link-in-react) and disable the link by changing the `onClick` function depending on the status.